# Check if path exist

Tags: uri

I want add export link in some place if current path plus '/export' exists. But can't understand how check such urls. The problem is when path exists with less number of arguments `drupal_valid_path()` returns TRUE. For example I have path 'reports' but don't have path 'reports/export'.
I check paths like this:

```
$export_path = current_path() . '/export';
if (drupal_valid_path($export_path)) {
    $export_options = drupal_get_query_parameters();
    $link_options = array(
       'attributes' => array(
            'class' => array('open'),
            'target' => '_blank',
        ),
        'query' => $export_options,
    );
    $vars['print_links'] = l('', $export_path, $link_options);
}
```

How do I need check paths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solve this problem by addng code above.

```
$exposed_args_count = count(explode('/', $export_path));
$menu_item = menu_get_item($export_path);
if (($menu_item['number_parts'] == $exposed_args_count) && drupal_valid_path($export_path)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check it simply using **arg()** function.
e.g you have path as `www.example.com/testpage/export`

```
$export_path = arg(0)."/".arg(1);
//$export_path will print its as 'testpage/export'
```

So you can use the `if` condition as

```
if ($export_path=='testpage/export')) {

//Your data export code

}
```

Comment: There could be many arguments in urls and many urls to check. So it's not correct to check like you wrote.

Comment: Thats fine. But i think there can be params in the urls that you know already.